# How to map (such as) ata4.01 to device?

Tags: centos-6, smart

I'm seeing messages link this on a CentOS 6.8 server:

```
Jun 12 22:01:12 myserver kernel: ata4: lost interrupt (Status 0x51)
Jun 12 22:01:12 myserver kernel: ata4.01: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
Jun 12 22:01:12 myserver kernel: ata4.01: failed command: SMART
Jun 12 22:01:12 myserver kernel: ata4.01: cmd b0/d5:01:09:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/10 tag 0 pio 512 in
Jun 12 22:01:12 myserver kernel:         res 40/00:00:06:4f:c2/00:00:00:00:00/10 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
Jun 12 22:01:12 myserver kernel: ata4.01: status: { DRDY }
Jun 12 22:01:12 myserver kernel: ata4: soft resetting link
Jun 12 22:01:13 myserver kernel: ata4.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jun 12 22:01:13 myserver kernel: ata4.01: configured for UDMA/133
Jun 12 22:01:13 myserver kernel: ata4: EH complete
```

How do I easily map ata4.01 to know which device so I know what hard drive it is? This system has two internal 80 GB drives and two eSATA 2TB drives and one USB externally connected drive.

Is there a command or anyone know of a script that does this?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a *direct* link, but following the maze of symlinks under `/sys` …

```
ls -ld /sys/class/ata_device/dev4.*/device/../../host*/target*/*/block/sd*

ls -ld /sys/class/block/sd*/device/../../../link*/dev4.*
```

… should lead to the corresponding `sd*` devices.